# Should I create a theme or a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

I'm working on a pro bono project to try to learn WordPress. I've been provided with a rough design (see screenshot below) and I'm struggling trying to think of how to approach the issue.

My main issue is the whole image gallery side of it. In order to make it so that my client can take the site and not have *me* create the content in the future I feel like I will have to develop a plugin to make it look/function.

I've searched for other plugins that are like this but nothing quite does what I need it.

[image: website design]

I guess I'm mostly looking for guidance on what my next steps should be for this.

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from doing both.  At a bare minimum on sites I do, I'm generally rolling my own theme as well as a catch all utility plugin to handle non presentation type things.  A general guidelines is to not put anything that generates content in a theme.  A user should be able to switch themes without losing any content.

Comment: You could hook the slide show in using the loop_start hook with a conditional tag.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I'm new to the whole WordPress development scene so your advice is very helpful.

Comment: @BradDalton, I'm not quite to the point at which I understand this comment but I may find it helpful in the future! I will research further.

Comment: Good luck @LukeP and I think it's awesome that you're trying to learn it from the ground up (only real way to do it imo).  Happy coding!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to keep the business logic out of the theme. Dealing with images is always an edge case, because they *do* affect presentation, which is usually a theme job.

But the logic of how to get and order these images, the JavaScript parts and the backend are probably better in a separate code base. That is also easier for version control, because you can focus on *one* problem that is complex enough already.
I would just add a custom action to the theme, maybe like this:

```
do_action( 'content_before' );
```

See ticket [#21506](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21506) for a discussion of standard theme hooks.

Your plugin could then insert its content with:

```
add_action( 'content_before', 'your_plugin_callback' );
```

Provide a separate stylesheet, but offer an [option for themes to override that](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/91200/73) per `add_theme_support()`.

And the best thing is: you can reuse the code in the next project if you keep it flexible enough. Or share it on wordpress.org. Or sell it.

See also: [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/73)

Comment: Good stuff! Thank you Toscho. This is enough to get me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('loop_start', 'slider_function');
function slider_function() {
if ( function_exists( 'soliloquy_slider' ) ) {
soliloquy_slider();
}}
```

Something like this custom function added to your functions file will enable you to hook in the sliders template tag so it displays before the content.

This assumes using the [Soliloquy slider plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/soliloquy-lite/) template tag.

This is an easier solution than creating your own action hook.

Comment: Your `add_action()` call to `loop_start` is there twice :)

Comment: Is this your site: `http://soliloquywp.com/`?