# Theme or Plugin: Where should I write my code?

Tags: plugins, themes

I'm facing a dilemma - whether to add my code into a theme or plugin? I'm creating an events plugin (/theme) that would allow college students to post their events and once approved, these events would be displayed to all.

While 'Create an event' form can be rendered using shortcode, I'm concerned about putting up event search pages, list of events (there will be thousands of events), 'My Events', 'Favorite Events' etc. Should these be rendered using shortcode OR as theme pages?

Would really appreciate your suggestions.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I create a theme or a plugin?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174124/should-i-create-a-theme-or-a-plugin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How Sharma just mentioned, both approaches are working well, but depending on the site type and scope and also it depends on the feature that needs to be implemented in your WordPress.

If in the future you will change the theme of your WordPress site and you just implemented a feature in your current theme, it will be lost.

How the sketch below shows, I suggest to add your design in theme or child theme (recommended) and all functionalities in a plugin

[image]

I always add shortcodes, widgets, custom post types and metaboxes in plugin because the theme will not be same forever but this way the functionalities from the plugin will be kept.

Hope this answer your question;

Comment: Thanks! In my case, the plugin is being installed privately - so theme and plugin can both be managed well. I'm wondering if rendering 1000s of custom, paginated posts being rendered 'inside' a page via short-code would create any performance issue.

Comment: @TheBigK If those 1000x posts are paginated there will be no problems regarding the performance and page loading speed.

Comment: Thanks, Cristian. If that is the case, I think I can figure out may way now. I've already checked rendering paginated content using shortcode and it seems to work absolutely fine. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen both approaches being taken. However, I'd suggest going with a plugin. If the feature is tied to the theme, you may have troubles in updating the theme.

If everything is in a plugin, you can can make changes relatively easier as data is safe with plugin and even change the complete look and feel by selecting another theme.

I'd suggest using shortcodes and using WP's inbuilt features (use custom post types, taxonomies for tagging etc.) so your data is not tied to a specific theme.